# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this2.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and am getting this error to use the search bottom in my application:

[image]

This is my code:

[image]

I am also new to Stack Overflow; let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to add your code directly to the question as markdown text rather than uploading it as an image. This makes it easier for others to copy/reproduce your code and see any errors that might occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of methods how to fix the issue:

- use an arrow function instead:

```
search  = (terms) => {}
```

- Bind `this` into your functions you intend to use `this.search = this.search.bind(this);` inside your App constructor() after `this.state`

Have a look for more details: [React - How to fix this.setState is not a function error](https://sebhastian.com/this-setstate-is-not-a-function/)